# x64 program returns the correct SIDT value occasionally (x64 assembly)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, assembly, 64-bit

I use Visual studio 2012 and I created a x64 bit program that returns the value of the SIDT function (without the offset). The problem is that when I initially run the program, it returns the right value, but when I run the program multiple times, it returns the right value occasionally

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
extern "C" unsigned long long int sidt_function();

int main()
{
   printf("%llx\n", sidt_function());
   _getch();
   return 0;
}
```

**sidt_function.asm**:

```
.code

sidt_function proc
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
sub rsp, 130h
sidt tbyte ptr [rbp-10]
mov rax, [rbp-8]
leave
ret

sidt_function endp
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each core (physical or virtual) in a multi-core CPU has its own IDT. What you're seeing are the IDTR values for different cores in your system. None of them are incorrect.

Comment: So that's why I am getting eight different values each time...I have a Core i7 with 4 physical cores and 8 threads. Thank you so much!